# If $m\mid n$ then $p^m-1\mid p^n-1$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, divisibility

I know $m$ ,$n$ are two positive integer numbers such that $m\mid n$. If $p$ is a prime number, I want to show $p^m-1\mid p^n-1$.

Comment: Hint: You don't need $p$ prime.

Comment: Which lets you reduce to the question of showing $q-1\mid q^d-1$.

Answer (score 2):

Rewrite $n=d\cdot m$ and observe that we are looking to show

$p^m-1|(p^m)^d-1$.

This boils down to showing that $x-1|x^d-1$, which should not be a problem.

$\textbf{Note}$: We don't need $p$ to be prime.

Comment: Sorry about the edit. I misread and have now rolled back

Comment: @robjohn No problem, it happens.